# What is the difference between Action and Actions in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I would like to know the difference between `Action` and `Actions` in *Selenium*

Answer (score 3):

### Action:

In `Selenium`, **`Action`** is an interface which represents a single user-interaction action. It is defined in `org.openqa.selenium.interactions`. It contains one of the most widely used method `perform()`. You can find more about the implementing Classes and Methods in this [**`link`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Action.html).

### Action Example:

In the below image, if we mouse hover the keyword `Action`, the violet colored **`I`** indicates that `Action` is an interface.

[image: InterfaceAction]

---

### Actions:

In `Selenium`, **`Actions`** is a Class. It is defined in `org.openqa.selenium.interactions`. This is the user-facing API for emulating complex user gestures. **`Actions`** Class implements the builder pattern, which can build a CompositeAction containing all actions specified by the method calls. You can find more about the Method Summary in this [**`link`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).

### Actions Example:

In the below image, if we mouse hover the keyword `Actions`, the green colored **`C`** indicates that `Actions` is a Class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Action is [an interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Action.html) :

```
public interface Action
```

Action Interface representing a single user-interaction action.

VS

Actions is a [Class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) that extends from Object

```
public class Actions
extends java.lang.Object
```

The user-facing API for emulating complex user gestures. Use this class rather than using the Keyboard or Mouse directly.

Edit:

Thanks to @mrfreester pointed out. You can string a bunch of actions together using `Actions`, and then once you call `build()` it will store that set of steps as an `Action`. Once you have an Action, you can call `perform()` to execute that set of steps.

Comment: Just to add more context... You can string a bunch of actions together using `Actions`, and then once you call `build()` it will store that set of steps as an `Action`. Once you have an `Action,` you can call `perform()` to execute that set of steps.

Comment: Thanks! This will add some clarification. I will edit the answer to include this!

Comment: update on perform, you can only add perform() instead of build to make your code work.