# Selenium: Action is an interface? Reason behind the Design decision?

Tags: selenium

Selenium Action is an interface that has only the perform() method, which executes the composite action.

Why is it an interface or what is the design decision selenium people have reasoned to keep it this way.

```
public class ActionBuildPerform {
    public static void main(String... args) {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("file://C:/selectable.html");
      WebElement one = driver.findElement(By.name("one"));
      WebElement three = driver.findElement(By.name("three"));
     WebElement five = driver.findElement(By.name("five"));
      // Add all the actions into the Actions builder.
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
              .click(one)
             .click(three)
             .click(five)
             .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
       // Generate the composite action.
       Action compositeAction = builder.build();
       // Perform the composite action.
       compositeAction.perform();
      }
   }
```

Moreover statement like

```
 Action compositeAction = builder.build();
```

confuses me up since I always think The reference variable should be a class. I understand this means it could be any class that implements that Action interface (but still can't wrap my head around it) . Maybe there is a bit of java fundamentals issue with me. If somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Action and Actions in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492229/what-is-the-difference-between-action-and-actions-in-selenium)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here is the documentation for Actions http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp#actions