# Locate a row with a specific text and click that row's icon in the last column

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver, html-table, cucumber

I want to find specific row in a mat-table, and I want to click a specific mat-icon. However I don't know how to use xpath in the **case of mat-icon**. My code is find the table, and iterate over the rows to find specific row. After that it should click on mat-icon in the last column. Maybe can I find it by its name? Here is my code:

```
public void clickIconFromSelectedRow(String text, String icon) {
    WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-table[@role='table']"));
    List<WebElement> tableRows = baseTable.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-row[@role='row']"));
    for (WebElement row : tableRows){
        List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-cell[@role='cell']"));
        for (WebElement col : cols) {
            if (col.getText().equals(text)) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("SOME XPATH AND + text + TEXT")).click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the HTML for your information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHpug.jpg)

**Note:** in the last column, there must be several mat-icons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things here:

- You are constructing the *list* *`tableRows`* with respect to the [*WebElement*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) `baseTable`. So within the xpath instead of `By.xpath("//mat-row[@role='row']")` you need *`By.xpath("./mat-row[@role='row']")`*
- The text ***Test*** is actually within the descendent of the element `//mat-cell[@role='cell']` so you may like to go deeper as `./mat-cell[@role='cell']/div/div[text()]`.
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  public void clickIconFromSelectedRow(String text, String icon) {
      WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-table[@role='table']"));
      List<WebElement> tableRows = baseTable.findElements(By.xpath("./mat-row[@role='row']"));
      for (WebElement row : tableRows){
          List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.xpath("./mat-cell[@role='cell']/div/div[text()]"));
          for (WebElement col : cols) {
              if (col.getText().equals(text)) {
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("SOME XPATH AND + text + TEXT")).click();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question: why did You add the '/div/div[text()]' block to mat-cell?

Comment: @Kriszto93 Wasn't a comment :) but a well researched canonical answer. See the second bullet point: _The text Test is actually within the descendent of the element //mat-cell[@role='cell'] so you may like to go deeper as ./mat-cell[@role='cell']/div/div[text()]._

Comment: edited ;) Btw if I want to click on the mat-icon in the last column, do I need only xpath or use Action class?

Comment: [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) and [_css_selector_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) are two different type of [_locator strategies_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447). Generally, [_click()_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) is much proven and it works. However at times you have to take help of [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) and [Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499252/7429447).

Answer (score 0):

Really, I think you are over-complex a simple problem using xPath. I I imagine you has a mat-table with a column like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=dataIndex"> 
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="doSomething(element,i)">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Why not search the row asking the dataSource and use?

```
   this.doSomething(element,i)
```

Comment: I found the row, I just want to find the xpath of the icon by it's name